# how to capture the details and then validate after?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have few textboxes and i want the user to first capture the details into the textboxes and then when he/she click save button the validation must start in sequence. See my code below am not sure of my logic. please help me.

```
       if (txtFullNames.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Please enter your fullname";
            txtFullNames.Focus();

            //txtFullNames.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;  
        }
        else if(!Regex.IsMatch(txtFullNames.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]"))
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Fullname must not contain a number";
        }
        else if (txtSurname.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Please enter your Surname";
            txtSurname.Focus();
        }
        else if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtSurname.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]"))
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Surname must not contain a number";
        }
        else if (txtEmail.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Please enter your Email Address";
            txtEmail.Focus();
        }
        else if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*             [a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"))
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Please enter you valid email address";
            txtEmail.Focus();
        }
        else if (cboGender.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Please select your Gender";
            cboGender.Focus();
        }
        else if (cboCompany.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Please select your Company";
            cboCompany.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtUserName.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Please enter your Username";
            txtUserName.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtPassword.Password.Length == 0)
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Please enter your password";
            txtPassword.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtConfirmPassword.Password.Length == 0)
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Please confirm your password";
            txtConfirmPassword.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtPassword.Password != txtConfirmPassword.Password)
        {
            Errormessage.Text = "Both password must match";
        }
        #endregion
        else
        {

            SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your validation in a method and call this method when the save button is clicked

Example

```
public void validateFields(){
// check your fields
}

private void validatetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       validateFields();
}
```

Comment: it is inside the button

Comment: Create a validation method for the textboxes outside the button code. And call this method when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're after is [Validations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here's an example.

```
 class Example_Validation : ValidationRule
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Example of a simple validation, that can have different validation error contents.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">A string in this case</param>
    /// <param name="cultureInfo"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var str = value as string;      // Convert to our string
        var sb = new StringBuilder();   // For the error messages
        var valid = true;               // Rather obvious

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        {
            valid = false;
            sb.AppendLine("Null or white space is not valid.");
        }
        else if (str.Length < 5)
        {
            valid = false;
            sb.AppendLine("String too short (less than 5).");
        }

        return new ValidationResult(valid, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

You can have a look at a template I wrote here: [big mvvm template](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768427/The-big-MVVM-Template)